# Refiner badge bug

Tags: support, badges

I didn't answer or edit 50 questions within the last 12 hours. Why am I receiving [this badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/104/)?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit and answer a question. The editing and answering need to take place within 12 hours of each other and your answer score needs to be > 0 (the answer score is not part of the timing).

If you do the above 50 times, no matter how many days, weeks, months or years that takes, you get the refiner badge.

Comment: Thank you. The problem seems to be on the description of the badge, which imo is deceptive.

Comment: @PedroLobito No it is not, it is very clear. Edit and answer 50 questions and then it says __both__ actions, so obviously not related to the number 50, but to "edit and answer".

Comment: Whatever you say, I really don't care, but the badge description is misleading and I'm not the only one having this doubt.